# SVG - Filling Rectangle with Jet Colour Scheme

Tags: html, svg

What is the correct way to fill an SVG rectangle with jet colour scheme? Using multiple stops in `linearGradient` does not seem to work.

Edit, I am trying to fill the a rectangle with one of the following colour gradient. [image]

Comment: "jet colour scheme" is not a standard or anything, so I'm assuming most people (like me) have no idea what you're referring to, can you be more specific as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: http://cresspahl.blogspot.com/2012/03/expanded-control-of-octaves-colormap.html - If I'm understanding this properly, you're trying to create a rainbow gradient that goes from red to blue and includes the colors in between. Is this correct?

Comment: @BSMP: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the MDN code with a rainbow example

```
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients -->

<svg width="120" height="240" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#d30000"/>
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ffff05"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#05ff05"/>
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#05ffff"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#041ae0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#Gradient2)"/>

</svg>
```

in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9bmvr5hd/

Answer (score 0):

The BbwrR gradient is the example used in [Mozilla's SVG - Gradients documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients):

```html
<svg width="120" height="240" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="25%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="50%"/>
        <stop class="stop3" offset="75%"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="blue"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0"/>
        <stop offset="75%" stop-color="red"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        #rect1 { fill: url(#Gradient1); }
        .stop1 { stop-color: blue; }
        .stop2 { stop-color: black; stop-opacity: 0; }
        .stop3 { stop-color: red; }
      ]]></style>
  </defs>
 
  <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect x="10" y="120" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#Gradient2)"/>
  
</svg>
```

I swapped the location of the red and blue and adjusted the offset percentages to try to make it look more like your image. You should be able to just change the colors and add/remove stops for the others.